# How to specify the cross-platform path to the icon?

Tags: java, path, icons, cross-platform

I am a complete zero in Java, I just need to edit part of the source code and I'm stuck.

And so, I have the following code:

```
package net.technicpack.legacywrapper;

import com.beust.jcommander.Parameter;
import com.beust.jcommander.internal.Lists;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public final class StartupParameters {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final String[] args;
    public StartupParameters(String[] args) {
        this.args = args;
        auth_player_name = args[0];
        auth_session = args[1];
    }
    @Parameter
    private List<String> parameters = Lists.newArrayList();

    private String auth_player_name;

    private String auth_session;

    @Parameter(names = {"--gameDir"}, description = "Pack directory")
    private String gameDir;

    @Parameter(names = {"--assetsDir"}, description = "Assets directory")
    private String assetsDir;

    @Parameter(names = {"--width"}, description = "Sets the width of the minecraft window to be fixed to this.")
    private int width = -1;

    @Parameter(names = {"--height"}, description = "Sets the height of the minecraft window to be fixed to this.")
    private int height = -1;

    @Parameter(names = {"--title"}, description = "The title bar text for the Minecraft frame.")
    private String title = "Minecraft";

    @Parameter(names = {"--icon"}, description = "The title bar icon for the Minecraft frame.")
    private String icon = "path to .ico";

    public List<String> getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }

    public String getAuthPlayerName() { return auth_player_name; }
    public String getAuthSession() { return auth_session; }
    public String getGameDirectory() { return gameDir; }
    public String getAssetsDirectory() { return assetsDir; }
    public int getWidth() { return width; }
    public int getHeight() { return height; }
    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public String getIconPath() { return icon; }
}
```

Actually, the very part of the code that needs to be edited:

```
@Parameter(names = {"--icon"}, description = "The title bar icon for the Minecraft frame.")
private String icon = "path to .ico";
```

Instead of "path to .ico" I need to specify the path to the icon here, but I do not know how. This path must be cross-platform so that everything works on both Windows and Linux. For example, the icon will be located at:

Windows:
C:/Users/Some user/AppData/Roaming/.gamefolder/res/icon.png

Or Linux:
/home/someuser/.gamefolder/res/icon.png

How to specify these paths in the code? Also, I think it would be easier to put the icon in the JAR file so that it can be read from it. But then again, I do not know how to do this. Please help.

Comment: You can start by building the path relative to `System.getProperty("user.home")`; but for a command line argument, it should probably accept whatever value is passed.

Comment: can you please tell me how to use it in my case? I really don’t understand where it needs to be written in order for this to work...